# Adding values form different mySQL-tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My tables:

```
cloe_Pictures:
   id  | title | mainKategorie
  1001 | ABC   |      1
  1002 | BCD   |      1
  1003 | need  |      2
  1004 | FGH   |      3


cloe_htbl_Kategorie:
   bezeichnung | kategorieId
          Kat1 |      1
          BLO  |      2
          Peng |      3
          yxz  |      4

cloe_Kategorie:
        picID | kategorieId
         1003 |      1
         1005 |      2
         2003 |      3
         3003 |      4
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT pic.title, kat.bezeichnung AS kategorie
FROM cloe_Pictures pic, cloe_htbl_Kategorie kat
WHERE pic.mainKategorie=kat.kategorieId 
      AND pic.mainKategorie=1
```

gives:

```
         title | kategorie
          ABC  | Kat1  
          BCD  | Kat1
```

My question is: How can I include all records from table cloe_Kategorie WHERE ID=1
that I have in the end a table like this:

```
    title | kategorie
      ABC  | Kat1  
      BCD  | Kat1
      need | Kat1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a join between `cloe_Kategorie` and `cloe_Pictures` as well. Something like below

```
SELECT pic.title, kat.bezeichnung AS kategorie
             FROM cloe_Pictures pic, cloe_htbl_Kategorie kat
             WHERE pic.mainKategorie=kat.kategorieId AND pic.mainKategorie=1

UNION

SELECT pic.title, kat.bezeichnung AS kategorie
             FROM cloe_htbl_Kategorie kat JOIN cloe_Kategorie ck
             ON kat.kategorieId  = ck.kategorieId
             AND ck.picID = 1003 
             JOIN cloe_Pictures pic ON pic.id = ck.picID
```

Comment: sorrry: this query has an empty result

Comment: my next idea is to make two querys. select * from cloe_Pictures WHERE mainKategorie=1 and: select * from cloe_Kategorie WHERE kategorieId = 1. and bring them together ...

Comment: gives to much records with unlogical content

Comment: @hamburger, Problem is I am not trying it. just the condition needs to be placed rightly. Try now. See I have moved the condition `ck.picID = 1003`

Comment: i confirm this Answer is Correct, i have created the schema and executed this qry.

Comment: @Yazan, Thanks for trying it and confirming. Appreciate the effort.